Is there a way by code to feed multiple NM into a 2" knockout in a main breaker?
My replacement main circuit box has only four 1/2" knockouts and 3 up to 2" knockouts (one will be service).  Did they happen to make cable clamps for the larger holes that you are allowed to put a lot of 12/2 or 14/2 NM into and would this meet code?
I know the manufacturer specifies this, but this is the only side I can use without running wire nuts

Seems funny a panel would only have four 1/2 inch knock outs.

Can you edit your question with more information.  Why is only 4 knockouts handy.  Maybe a picture of the new panel.  Unless you need to remove the old panel, can use it as a junction box with conduit to the new box.  2 inch conduit will hold quite a bit of circuits if using conduit wire(THHW?)

Drawings for the OP's new panel, FYI

Try a NM844
Since the KOs in question are multi-size (1" to 2"), the 1.25" NM844 is the best bet I know of -- it can take 9-10 ordinary-sized (14 or 12 AWG) NM cables.

It can be difficult to do with an existing cabinet, but I've taken a 4s cover,  trimmed 1/4" off one side, placed inside cabinet and bolted to cabinet. Then drilled (7/8") holes though cabinet and 4s cover where I desired. Then to deal with increased thickness you need to use connectors with locknuts rather than snap-in types.

I had this kind of instance in one home. Electrician used 2 of these 2" knockout plugs and drilled a hole to fit a smaller cable clamp.
He put the knockouts back to back and use the cable clamp to hold them together.
